# My Windows 8.1 installation is not being detected

Tags: windows

Ubuntu DVD Installation is not detecting my Windows 8.1 during installation. Why is this?

Comment: What do you mean? Is the installation DVD cannot detect your windows partition or your windows installation did not display on the boot loader (GRUB)

Comment: Sorry for the late response. The Windows Installation does not display on the boot loader.

Comment: All I get is the Erase Disc and something else options. Just would like to know if I continue using the something else and select the free partition if I can still keep both operating systems running.If so how?

Comment: Both system will still run if you leave the Windows partition unchanged. What kind of system are you running? UEFI or BIOS. If you see the GRUB screen when boot with the DVD -> UEFI. And you said free partition mean an empty partition (with a file system on it) or unallocated space?

Answer (score 0):

Try 'Boot-repair' option:

```
 sudo apt-get install boot-repair
 boot-repair
```

Fixes almost all GRUB/bootloader problems.

Comment: Im very new, no non-existent to ubuntu\unix so i don"t understand understand this

Comment: open Ctrl+alt+t and type the following commands. It'll repair any boot problems.